# Null Reference error when using any operator other than == in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am currently using ASP-NetCore razor pages to create a web application. In it there are two similar pages which pull two complementary pieces of data. As a result the code for their Pagemodel are nearly identical, with the sole difference being a usage of != instead of ==. In spite of this, the one which uses == runs without issue, while the other one has the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method(Closure , AccountRequest )
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.<MoveNextCore>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<Aggregate_>d__6`3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Webapp.Pages.SalesReps.CompletedAccountRequests.IndexModel.<OnGetAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in fakepath\Pages\SalesReps\CompletedAccountRequests\Index.cshtml.cs:line 30
```

The code which works is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApp.Data;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Pages.SalesReps.NewAccountRequests
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AccessionContext _context;

        public IndexModel(AccessionContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<AccountRequest> AccountRequest { get;set; }
        public IList<String> Claims { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var claim = from c in User.Claims where c.Type == "SalesRep" select c.Value;
            Claims = claim.ToList();
            var requests = 
                from a in _context.AccountRequests 
                where ((Claims.Contains(a.Group.SalesRep)) 
                    || (Claims.Contains(a.Group.Manager))) 
                    && a.RequestStatus == 0 
                orderby a.RequestDate 
                select a;

            if (requests != null)
            {
                AccountRequest = await requests.ToListAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this is the code which causes the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApp.Data;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Pages.SalesReps.CompletedAccountRequests
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AccessionContext _context;

        public IndexModel(AccessionContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<AccountRequest> AccountRequest { get;set; }
        public IList<String> Claims { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var claim = from c in User.Claims where c.Type == "SalesRep" select c.Value;
            Claims = claim.ToList();
            var requests = 
                from a in _context.AccountRequests 
                where ((Claims.Contains(a.Group.SalesRep)) 
                    || (Claims.Contains(a.Group.Manager))) 
                    && a.RequestStatus != 0 
                orderby a.RequestDate 
                select a;
            AccountRequest = await requests.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the actual page.

```
@page
@model WebApp.Pages.SalesReps.CompletedAccountRequests.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Date Completed
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].PracticeName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].GroupID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].Group.SalesRep)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].RequestedBy)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].RequestDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].RequestStatus)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].ClientIDS)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].CompletedBy)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountRequest[0].CompletedDate)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.AccountRequest) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompletedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PracticeName)
            </td>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GroupID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Group.SalesRep)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestedBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.RequestStatus == 1)
                {
                    Html.Display("Completed");
                } else if(item.RequestStatus == 2)
                {
                    Html.Display("Denied");
                } else if (item.RequestStatus == 3)
                {
                    Html.Display("Under Different Group");
                } else if (item.RequestStatus == 4)
                {
                    Html.Display("Account Closed");
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientIDS)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompletedBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompletedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.AccountRequestID">Details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Why is the use of a != operator causing such an error and what can I do to fix it?

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Try `!(a.RequestStatus == 0)` instead of `a.RequestStatus != 0`

Comment: `fakepath\Pages\SalesReps\CompletedAccountRequests\Index.cshtml.cs:line 30` <= (from your stack trace), What is this code doing? Can you share this?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `!(a.RequestStatus.Equals(0))`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have tried both of your suggestions and unfortunately neither work.

Comment: The error you are receiving has a logical reason.  You're trying to dereference a reference variable that contains null.  It would be better to find out what that logical reason is anyway.  As @Igor points out, you haven't shown us the code that is actually throwing the exception.

Comment: @Igor. That code points towards AccountRequest = await requests.ToListAsync(); in the second code block above

Comment: @DavidBelinsky: It would appear that `requests` is null.

Comment: I will edit the question to add the page itself. one second

Comment: I don't think it's the page.  The exception quite clearly points to line 30, which reads `AccountRequest = await requests.ToListAsync();`  The only place where a null reference exception can occur there is the dot operator on the `requests` variable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The code which throws the error is in the question above. It is within that second code block, as that second code block is the full model file which the exception is referring to.

Comment: Is this the line of code that throws the exception? `AccountRequest = await requests.ToListAsync();`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes that is the line. After your previous comment I have surrounded that line with an if statement to check if it is null, but it is still executed, meaning that the requests variable is not null. Ill edit my modification into the question above.

Comment: I think Igor has it right in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one of the returned records where `a.RequestStatus != 0` evaluates to true the `Group` relationship is null which would cause an NRE when evaluating either `a.Group.SalesRep` or `a.Group.SalesRep` for that record(s).

You could fix this by adding a check to see if the relationship exists like so (see below) but this might not be correct logically (*that depends on data constraints and what you consider bad data, really this is more of a business decision*).

```
var requests = 
    from a in _context.AccountRequests 
    where a.Group != null && // <-- added null check
        ((Claims.Contains(a.Group.SalesRep)) || (Claims.Contains(a.Group.Manager))) 
        && a.RequestStatus != 0 
    orderby a.RequestDate 
    select a;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has worked for me. I didn't even consider that the objects which AccountRequests has a relationship to could affect it in this way. I will make sure to watch out for this in future pages. As far as the logic portion of it I will add restrictions to what data may be entered for these objects so that this will not be presenting incorrect data.